# Keras: How to retrieve hidden states and/or cell states from several layers of LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, lstm-stateful

Need some help to capture hidden states and/or cell states for the following LSTM model for each layer

Excerpts from the python code that I could patch together:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, return_states=True, batch_input_shape=(10,features_set.shape[1], 5),stateful=True))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True, return_states=True,stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True, return_states=True,stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=50, stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units = 1))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(features_set, labels, epochs = 10, batch_size = 10, verbose=2)
```

How do I save the hidden states and/or cell states for each layer ? All that I could find online so far used examples with only one layer.

Please help.

Comment: So you want to save the model weights?

Comment: The model weights are not the same thing as hidden or cell states.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro .. I want to retrieve the hidden or cell states .. The first step that I found was to have  return_sequences(hidden states) or return_states(both) to be true. After that I am not be able to pull that data.